# Show Leaderboards with Firebase auth: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-games

I'm working on simple Android game and I want to use Google Play Games Leaderboard.
I was able to integrate and test it, and everything was fine until I decided that I also want Firebase. I was able to solve problems with double authentication, but I'm not able to show leaderboard screen.

Here is my code:

Authentication:

```
this.signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context,
        GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
                .requestServerAuthCode(context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .build())

private fun signInSilently() {
    signInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            onConnected(task.result)
        } else {
            val err = task.exception as ApiException
            onDisconnected(err.statusCode)
        }
    }
}

private fun onConnected(account:GoogleSignInAccount) {
    val serverAuth = account.serverAuthCode
    if (serverAuth != null) {
        val credential = PlayGamesAuthProvider.getCredential(serverAuth)
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        updateUI(firebaseAuth.currentUser)
                        analytics.event(Event.LOGIN)
                    } else {
                        updateUI(null)
                        analytics.event(Event.LOGIN_FAIL)
                    }
                }
    }

    needManualLogin = false
}
```

I used to show leaderboard with this code:

```
Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this,  GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)!!)
            .getLeaderboardIntent(id)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                startActivityForResult(it, LEADERBOARD_RC)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                loge("Failed to retrieve leaderboard: ${(it as ApiException).statusCode}")
            }
```

In result I have following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$zzf;
    at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.getLeaderboardsClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.noktigula.swipeygame.activity.LeaderboardActivity.showLeaderboard(LeaderboardActivity.kt:66)
```

Any help is appreciated!